# Combining two fips variables to create one fips code variable

Tags: sas, fips

I have one large SAS dataset and I am currently trying to create one FIPS code variable and at the moment I only have fipsStateCode and fipscountycode. Could someone please give me some guidance on how to go about this? The codes I have reviewed merge two datasets (by fips state and county code) but I only have one dataset.

Comment: Show us your data. Or an example that resembles what you are trying to do. Makes it much easier to provide a usable code answer

Comment: CATT() function with Z format if necessary?